# What's the best way to check for a valid session in a MEAN application using express-sessions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, mean-stack

I've been using `express-sessions` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sessions) along with `angular-route` in a MEAN project to manage user logins / authentication. Once a user logs in or registers, their user data (the entire `User` for example), is assigned to a session, and the user is then redirected to a new page: `#!/dashboard`.

To prevent users from accessing `#!/dashboard` without having first registered or logged in, I do a quick "session check", as I call it, from my angular controller, which passes to the angular factory, which quickly pings the server-side to do a check for a session object.

If a session exists, I return a boolean `true`, and if a session does not exist, I send a boolean `false`. I then do a conditional statement: if true, go ahead and continue grabbing posts or user data, etc on the `#!/dashboard` page (user's session is valid). If false, redirect to `/` where the login page exists (prevent user from accessing `#!/dashboard`).

This accomplishes my goal of preventing the user from now entering the `/#!/dashboard` in their browser without having logged in/registered, but this seems like a costly solution, and not very clean.

Is there a cleaner or better way to do this "session check" to prevent access to my back-end pages without a valid login session?

I've used express middleware somewhat, and maybe there's a way to do a quick check with every request?

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can improve my session checking?

Comment: if im not wrong, you are doing the session check from the client side (angular). Thats a huge security disaster waiting to happen, if not implemented really well.

Comment: Is your app fully single paged application

Comment: @Iceman Maybe this is a big security issue -- I am still learning -- more info: the way  I checked for a session was to create a server route, go to the back end, check in the `req` object if a session exists, if so, send back true, if not, send back false (as the variable, `validSession`). I then have a simple line in a callback function that runs in my angular factory once the response from the back-end is received: `if (!validSession) {  $location.url('/');  };` So, if the session is not valid, it redirects to the `/` page. Your method seems much better, but is this way described insecure?

Comment: @BOSS yeah it's a single pager using `angular-routes` -- there are separate pages, but they are partials being loaded in angular.

Comment: @Iceman Are you saying that in my code snippet (from my comment in this section) that because I do the conditional logic on the front end ie, `if (!validSession) { ... };` that this is where the security issue exists? Someone could modify my statement so that the `$location.url('/')` is not redirected to? Am I correct in understanding where the risk lives?

Comment: Yes, that one boolean, client-side check is the security loophole a hacker could exploit to gain access to a page he should not have seen. The workaround is to realize this is all fine: the UI is a kind of client-side data, which is virtually public. The inner data that hydrates this UI, though, should be protected. Therefore, it must be fetched at UI rendering time, and served to the client code based on the validity of the user session. It then all comes down to: can I trust the req/res mechanism from my client? Is it tamperable? => install safe software. Is there a middleman? => https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function secure_pass(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.loggedIn || req.path==='/login') {
        next();
    } else {
       res.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

This function takes care that if `session.loggedIn` is not set to true, then then the user is redirected to `/login`.

Now inject it as a middleware:

```
app.use(secure_pass);
```

Now any `app.get("/", myfunc);` after above line will now be "secured" through your `secure_pass` function.

Ofcourse, you could selectively inject the middleware for certain routes only as well instead of all:

```
app.get("/", secure_pass, myfunc);
```

*Note: The above is untested code. I just put it together fast to give you an idea for an approach.*

Comment: I am going to check this out here later today and play around. I really appreciate this example. I'll get back to you once I've gotten my hands dirty.

Comment: +1 For your help & the selective injection, very handy. I was able to create a function and inject it as noted, however, when I run `res.redirect('/');` if my session does not exist, I actually receive my entire html file in my client-side console, rather than experience page-redirection. I believe this is because I'm using `angular-route` and the partials system is interfering. (This is why I chose to use `$location` to handle my page redirect, rather than `res.redirect`). Do you have any idea if it's still possible to `res.redirect` while `angular-routes` (partials) is setup?

Comment: Using the custom middleware is the right answer -- for either session or for JWTs. Still wrestling with totally getting it all working, but the middleware solution, and injecting it into specific routes, is very helpful for checking for JWTs or session info...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AngularJS 2 in the front-end, there is the notion of [guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) to protect your routes from unauthorized access but this only handles the angular part of your app; you will need to protect your Express app as well through a module like passport. You may also consider token authentication instead of sessions with [passport](http://passportjs.org/) and [jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-token). I wrote 2 articles on how to authenticate your mean app both from the [back](http://spring.elevysi.com/posts/view/72/authenticating-a-mean-application-with-passport-and-mongodb---part-i-back-end) and [front](http://spring.elevysi.com/posts/view/73/authenticating-a-mean-application-with-passport-and-mongodb---part-ii-front-end---angularjs---jwt---guard---observable) ends using passport and jwt.

Comment: Going to scope all of this out, I did some reading last night that did suggest that JSON Web Tokens were better for single page apps. I will read your articles, play around, along with other solutions posted in this thread, and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever used `jsonwebtoken` (https://jwt.io)? It seems like I can get away with using JWTs alone (without Passport), no? (I wish for practice with Passport but just trying to find a more bare bones solution for this particular project). I've bookmarked your articles to come back to here later when I dig into Passport. +1 thank you for the resources, looks very detailed with good examples.

Comment: Passport in this case only authenticates your user given say a username and a password; you might achieve this elsewise if you wish so. express-jwt-token is a module for using jwt.io in your express app otherwise you will need to implement the library jwt.io yourself in your express app.